# make many process wait before the main process

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos, wait

I have this code:

```
Start "" robocopy F:\DATA1 D:\Backup\  
Start "" robocopy G:\DATA2 D:\Backup\    
Start "" robocopy H:\DATA3 D:\Backup\    
Start "" D:\Backup\rename.bat
```

How to make the `rename.bat` WAIT all process before execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: first method - use flag files (qtest.bat substituted for robocopy)
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")
COPY NUL "%tempfile%b">nul&START "" qtestd "%tempfile%b" f:\data1 d:\backup\
COPY NUL "%tempfile%c">nul&START "" qtestd "%tempfile%c" g:\data2 d:\backup\
COPY NUL "%tempfile%d">nul&START "" qtestd "%tempfile%d" h:\data3 d:\backup\
del "%tempfile%a"
:wait
timeout /t 1 >nul
FOR %%a IN (b c d) DO IF EXIST "%tempfile%%%a" GOTO wait
ECHO Start "" D:\Backup\rename.bat
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a process using flag files that should allow you to do the copies in parallel.

First, set up a flag file in the temporary directory by selecting a name using the random-number generator, and create a file with suffix "a" as a place-keeper.

Next, start each of the processes you require to run in parallel but put the process into its own batch in th following format:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO robocopy %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
PAUSE
DEL %1
EXIT
```

That is, first argument is the name of the flag file. In this case, you are executing **robocopy** with the remaining arguments. The `pause` is simply to simulate the `robocopy` operation.

The final operation before exiting is to delete the flag file.

Having submitted all of the jobs required, delete the "a" flagfile and execute the `:wait` loop until none of the flag files remains, which indicates each of the subsidiary batch files has ended.

Then run your renane procedure (but please change that name as `rename` is a batch keyword)

The `timeout` command prevents the batch becoming a processor-hog; it just waits for 1 second.

Another approach is to use the same `wait` loop, but wait for there to be no `robocopy` instances by executing `tasklist` and looking for a line beginning `robocopy.exe`. Wait until there are no such lines, then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `start`. You use start to not make them wait. See `start /?`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `start` with the `/w` or `start /wait` option.

```
Start "" /w robocopy F:\DATA1 D:\Backup\  
Start "" /w robocopy G:\DATA2 D:\Backup\    
Start "" /w robocopy H:\DATA3 D:\Backup\    
Start "" D:\Backup\rename.bat
```

Now `rename.bat` will not run until the previous commands have completed.

---

Source [Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

> **Syntax**
>
> `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`
>
> **Options:**
>
> `/W` or `/WAIT`  Start application and wait for it to terminate.
>                   (for an internal cmd command or a batch file this runs `CMD /K`)